# Возникают трудности со знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые знатоки. Рассейте, пожалуйста, смуту насчет знаков препинания в следующем предложении:

> Я за эксперименты — только пробуя можно найти что-то новое.

Хочется обособить "только пробуя". Путаюсь. Буду благодарен за пояснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое правило, согласно которому:

> Деепричастие, утеряв глагольный признак добавочного действия, может
> обрести значение наречия. В таком случае одиночное деепричастие не
> выделяется запятыми.

То есть здесь мы запятые не должны ставить.

Answer (score 1):

Как ответили ранее, запятая не нужна. Однако добавлю: в данном предложении вместо тире должно быть двоеточие, так как первая часть предложения ("Я за эксперименты") является выводом/следствием, а вторая - причиной; двоеточие между двумя частями предложения заменяется союзом "потому что".